# Is it safe to use a Spring @Transactional annotation on a Java 8 default interface method?

Tags: java, spring, transactions, annotations, java-8

The Spring documentation recommends against putting @Transactional annotations on interface methods because interface annotations are not inherited by classes. However, with Java 8 we can provide a concrete default implementation in the interface. If such a default interface method needs to be the transactional boundary, we have no other choice: we have to put the @Transactional annotation on the interface method.

Will this work (i.e. will spring respect the transaction boundary in this case)? If so, are there any hidden pitfalls to this approach?

Comment: If you need a default implementation of a method, why not create an abstract class instead of an interface?  The Java 8 API docs lead me to believe that interface default methods are primarily intended to allow the addition of new methods to an interface without breaking older implementations of that interface.

Comment: Interface default methods allow you to create [mixins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin), which are a much more powerful programming construct than traditional java interfaces. Whether there is a valid reason to use a mixin in a Service interface with Transactions is another issue, but it's not inconceivable. Using abstract classes will also work, but constrains you to a linear object hierarchy. Mixins are much more flexible.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Spring uses (among others) a `BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor` as an `Advisor` when generating a proxy bean for classes annotated with or containing methods annotated with `@Transactional`.

When the time comes to proxy it, it uses the bean's class type (with CGLIB) to generate the proxy. So we want to see if the `default` method annotated with `@Transactional` will be visible from the implementing class' point of view.

Here's a Java 8 SSCCE

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    Class<?> randomImplClass = RandomImpl.class;
    System.out.println(randomImplClass);
    Easy annotation = randomImplClass.getAnnotation(Easy.class);
    System.out.println("Class: " + randomImplClass);
    System.out.println("Class Annotation: " + annotation);

    Method method = randomImplClass.getMethod("doRandom");
    annotation = method.getAnnotation(Easy.class);
    System.out.println("Method: " + method);
    System.out.println("Method Annotation: " + annotation);
}

public static class RandomImpl implements Random{}
@Easy
interface Random {
    @Easy
    default void doRandom() {System.out.println("testing");};
}

@Target(value = {METHOD, TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Easy {}
```

which prints

```
class TestEnhancer$RandomImpl
Class: class TestEnhancer$RandomImpl
Class Annotation: null
Method: public default void TestEnhancer$Random.doRandom()
Method Annotation: @TestEnhancer$Easy()
```

Indicating that the annotation was inherited for the interface's method. It seems, therefore, that Spring will be able to add `@Transactional` behavior when the class has not overriden the `default` method. If it has overriden it, then annotations are not inherited.

Comment: Very nice test. To take it one step further, you can override the default implementation in RandomImpl and demonstrate that you have to put the annotation on the overriding method to be able to see it. I don't believe this is any different from using inheritance.

Comment: @JMB Right, I did it locally, but didn't post the example here. The last sentence covers it. I'll add it when I get home later.